# How do I get around chrome always "failing validation" on a Windows install?

Tags: google-chrome

When I ever I try to download Google Chrome at www.google.com/chrome I get a "failed validation." Why? And, how do I get around this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This problem occurs because of networking or transport errors between the Chrome download utility and the install. Unfortunately, there is no easy way to "fix" this issue. If you run into it however you can get around the problem by downloading the full *off-line* Chrome installer yourself. Google doesn't make this easy, and they don't expose this through a link or an API. In addition they expire the offline-copies on every release.

1. Go to http://googlechromereleases.blogspot.com/
2. Look for a full version number in a post: something like this `aa.b.cccc.ddd` an example may be `18.0.1025.151` (current as of the time of writing).
3. Take the cccc.ddd and insert them into a link like `http://dl.google.com/chrome/install/cccc.ddd/chrome_installer.exe`. As per the above example it should be `http://dl.google.com/chrome/install/1025.151/chrome_installer.exe`.

Now until the next release you may use `http://dl.google.com/chrome/install/1025.151/chrome_installer.exe`

[This answer was inspired by a post in 2010](http://groups.google.com/a/googleproductforums.com/d/msg/chrome/n-kFBeCRbw0/DjPGaKXI6EUJ)

Answer (score 0):

Try one of the offline installers listed [here](http://support.google.com/installer/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=126299).  They are standalone and don't use the chrome download manager but instead pack the entire install into a single .exe.  There is a single account version which is the default type of install only on your user account or a version which installs for all users.