# Chrome gives me "Update server not available: error 7"?

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome

I'm using Windows 7. For some weird reason when ever I go *About Chrome* and it tries to update I get *"Update server not available: error 7"*. Why is this? How do I get around this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because Chrome is having network problems, or more likely you're having network problems. Try to resolve this by [downloading an off-line copy directly](https://superuser.com/a/409042/11116).

Comment: "or more likely you're having network problems." so the solution is to 'download' a offline copy?

Comment: If it works.. it works.. Not sure why that's just a crappy message Google gives backs. Feel free to improve the answer or question.

Comment: I just amazed you were able to download a copy without an Internet connection... impressive.

Comment: I have a valid internet connection -- I'd guess it's bunk Google code authored by some underpaid MIT grad in a bright orange room... if we're going to make assumptions it's only fair I get one.

Comment: Oh I didn't realize these instructions were from Google. I hope you understand I was being sarcastic because I thought this was your solution to the problem... Either way, this seems like commonsense. Did it really need to be repeated?

Answer (score 0):

Reinstalling the Google Software Updater solved it for me.

Instructions:
http://support.google.com/chrome/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1367288