# Update server not available (error: 7)

Tags: google-chrome

I am getting an error when updating Google Chrome **canary**.

> Update server not available (error: 7)

I am behind a corporate firewall. Google Chrome can update fine.

How can I troubleshoot this issue?

Comment: Did you try this: http://superuser.com/questions/409043/chrome-gives-me-update-server-not-available-error-7?rq=1

Comment: No, but just had a look. Where can I find canary there?

Comment: I guess the idea behind referencing that post was to look for a manual download of the build you are looking for, and try that, as opposed to using the update server.

Comment: It seems as if canary is from the nightly builds. I can't find them there (http://superuser.com/questions/409041/how-do-i-get-around-chrome-always-failing-validation-on-a-windows-install/409042#409042)

Comment: Found it! https://download-chromium.appspot.com/